# Is there a way to draw a line behind a bounding box with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, vision

I'm writing an application for my undergrad dissertation which, at the fundamental level allows tracking of multiple objects from a video feed using the OpenCV library. To develop this idea a bit more, I'd like to be able to draw a line on the screen displaying the history of where the bounding box has been around the object I'm tracking.

I've noticed there's no sort of inbuilt function for doing this, so any pointers towards crafting something like this would be useful, since there isn't much online about this topic.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Can you provide an example image of what you are asking. It is not very clear to me. Also please read this forum's help section about how to ask a good question and what are appropriate questions. Have you tried anything? Please show some code of what you have tried. You can draw lines in OpenCV with cv2.line() and boxes with cv2.rectangle(). What else do you need it to do? see the documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9

Comment: @fmw42, Excuse the poor MS paint skills, but I want to achieve something like the following: https://i.imgur.com/yASa5DV.png - The red line indicates the path the object has taken as the video stream has been played

Comment: I still do not understand the issue. OpenCV has the ability to draw lines, rectangles and polygons and polylines. If you want to draw a path, then for each point of position draw a polyline to the previous point.

Comment: @fmw42, That's what i've been looking to achieve, sorry for my poor explanation of my issue

Comment: See cv2. polylines() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c

Comment: Take a look at [ball tracking](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/)